# Site hopping, non-related subjects, wasting time on the internet

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the term for embarking on an internet search that leads from one website to another, to another, to a totally different site of non-related subject, based on information found in each subsequent search? Say, start looking at recipes initially and end up on Mediaeval monks, via early explorers, or whatever...hopping around all over the place and finding that a day has passed without your realising it.

Comment: [*Stumbleupon.com*](http://www.stumbleupon.com/home) does it for you.

Comment: [Procrastination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrastination) comes to mind, although it is not specific for browsing the web, but it's common to procrastinate by surfing the interwebs. Cleaning the house instead of doing something else (learning for class) would be one non-web kind of procrastination.

Comment: Thank you _so_ much for not presuming that it should be a single term for this but allowing a phrase. However, you do seem to presume there is something _special_ for this.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/214/ "The Problem with Wikipedia"...

Comment: I'm not clear why you speak of it in such a pejorative way. If someone was browsing encyclopaedias in a library, would you consider that a waste of time?

Answer (score 19):

It's sometimes called [**falling down a rabbit hole**](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/rabbit-hole). A rabbit hole is presumed to be a meandering subterranean tunnel with many forks that branch off to unknown locations. The metaphor was used (well before the World Wide Web was conceived) in Lewis Carroll's [**Alice's Adventures in Wonderland**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland), in which Alice falls through a rabbit hole into a strange and fantastic world.

Comment: "You take the blue pill, the story ends. You wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe. You take the red pill, you stay in wonderland, and I show you how deep the rabbit hole goes." ―Morpheus, to Neo

Comment: The term is nowadays often used in the broad sense that the OP has in mind, but it should be noted that, as this answer says, Alice's going down the rabbit hole led her to a 'a strange and fantastic world'; those who are familiar with the source of the term may therefore not regard it as apt for the cases in which one has been led to something that is not particularly strange or fantastic, but merely far away from what one originally set out to do.

Comment: @jsw29 I think the reason it takes one away from the original pursuit is because it is fascinating or at least very interesting.  If it was boring claptrap that didn't pique the curiosity it would be easy to get back to the original quest. Case in point, reading a historical novel set in Newfoundland, I got distracted into learning more about Cromwell and the English Civil War(s). Strange and fantastic in the sense that my knowledge and recollection of that bit of history was pretty limited.

Answer (score 13):

> **surf the Web**
>
> *idiom*
>
> Definition: The term **surf**, used in the context of "*surf the
>   Web*", refers to the practice of browsing through Web sites: jumping
>   from one link to the other, following items of interest, watching
>   videos, and consuming all sorts of content; all on a variety of
>   different sites. Since the Web is essentially a series of links,
>   surfing the Web has become a very popular activity with millions of
>   people across the world
>  <sub>[About.com](http://websearch.about.com/od/s/g/Surf.htm)</sub>

Comment: It's not so much a series of links as it is one of tubes...

Comment: @talrnu I finally got the joke -- haha good one!

Answer (score 6):

Most of the really cool kids call it “surfing.” They’re always flying by me on these huge, trending waves and flippin me the bird. But I don’t do cool, I don’t trend, and in the insane yet immortal words of Lieutenant Colonel Bill Kilgore, [“Charlie don’t surf!”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWW1FeT1EyQ) So, as for me, I'm with Charlie and mean to [**meander**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=meander+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=meander+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0j0i7i30l4.0.0.4.61217...........0.qM2YkR2dgH4&gws_rd=ssl). see, Google

> [**Web Meandering**](http://michaelbales.com/)
>
> Confession: I like to meander on the web and find things I didn’t know I wanted to know. I’m not talking topics important to me, such as U.S. politics, for which I visit favorite blogs and news sites way too often. Meandering to me means wandering to find serendipitous discoveries.
>
> For a long time I’ve relied on [*MetaFilter*](http://www.metafilter.com/) and [*Boing Boing*](http://boingboing.net/) for these excursions. Now I’ve found another detour that leads to the most unexpected findings, such as [*Forget Everything you thought you knew about Pole Dancing*](http://www.listropolis.com/2011/12/forget-everything-you-thought-you-knew-about-pole-dancing/) and [*Geeklist*](https://geekli.st/home), the first social network for developers and the tech community.
>
> This latest blow to productivity is [*Listropolis*](http://www.listropolis.com/), which bills itself as the list of lists. *Listropolis* even lists *11 Sites With All the Lists You’ll Ever Need* and *10 Sites for Finding Wonderful Things*.
>
> *Listropolis*, like my other web diversions, is online [*bricolage*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bricolage) — the art of assembling diverse found objects. Luckily it has plenty of lists for improving productivity. From Cracked Window

There are times, however, when I just don’t feel like meandering (Mama told me there be days like these), and so, on those strange days, I choose instead to [**Wander**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=wander+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=wander+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0j0i10j0l2j0i10.0.0.5.225718...........0.CwkGrZCf81k&gws_rd=ssl) the Web! see, Google

> [**Wandering the Web**](http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2355&context=atg)
>
> Although most of us may not recognize it, Pop culture surrounds us. We see it portrayed in television, cyberspace, radio, advertising, toys, art, literature, games, and music. As a source for pop culture information, the Web is a treasure trove; it contains a wealth of information in that area. With that in mind, I invite you to explore a selection of those pop culture Websites, below. They are arranged loosely by topic, but as pop culture is by nature rather free-form and ever-changing, the categories serve as guidelines only. At these Websites, you may find things that surprise, inform, interest, entertain, or even startle you, which is what makes pop culture such a fascinating area. See, Against the Grain Vol. 21 / Issue 6 / Article 10

Answer (score 6):

The phrase "[yak shaving](http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2005/03/dont_shave_that.html)" fits this very well ... see here embodied as a gif: 
[Story of my life](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoPWi.jpg)

> [**yak shaving**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving): 2.(idiomatic)
>   A less useful activity done to consciously or unconsciously procrastinate about a larger but more useful task.
>   *I looked at a reference manual for my car just to answer one question, but I spent the whole afternoon with my nose buried in it, just yak shaving, and got no work done on the car itself.*
>    <sub>(Wiktionary)</sub>

Comment: And some other reasonable descriptions of the phrase (My rep prevents me from including these in the answer):

 - Urban Dictionary (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yak%20shaving)
 - Scott Hanselmann (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YakShavingDefinedIllGetThatDoneAsSoonAsIShaveThisYak.aspx)
 - Wicktionary (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving)

Answer (score 4):

**Tab Explosion**

Two of the most common places to get lost on the internet are Wikipedia and TV Tropes. The latter (of course) has page dedicated to just this sort of thing, and they call it [Tab Explosion](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrowserNarcotic?from=Main.TabExplosion) after the fact that some sites can lead you to open interesting links in a new tab... if you find only 2 or 3 interesting links on every page you'll still end up with a huge amount of open tabs in short order.

WARNING: Don't click the link if you actually have things to do today.

Comment: +1 for invoking TV Tropes. Now what was I meant to be doing?

Comment: +1 for the warning. Even if I should really -1 it just to keep the link buried as deep as possible, saving many people from the subsequent Tab Explosion.

Answer (score 1):

A web crawler is an autonomous computer program that does just what you describe: it aimlessly follows links from one website to another, *crawling the web* to form a map which search engines and the like can use to analyze the structure of the internet.

To be clear: I'm suggesting the term *crawling the web* as an answer to this question.

Comment: Seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @EleventhDoctor The question asks for a term describing the act of visiting a series of websites. The term emphasized in my answer, *crawling the web*, describes this exact act. How is this more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: @talmu The original answer read to me more like a fact apropos of the question than an answer. I see that you've added a clarifying sentence at the end now in any case.